# problem in express routing url manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, express, routes, path

Need help in express routing
When user goes to /page2 it should only see localhost:3000/page2 instead it is showing localhost:3000/page2.html

I have 3 html pages with some data. Lets say page1.html,page2.html and page3.html. I made a server using express and created routing like this
`App.get(“/page2” ,(req,res)=>{ Res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,’public’,”page2.html));`

});
When i click on `<a href=“/page2”>Go to page 2.</a>`
It is opening page2.html but at the same time url is also changing to localhost:3000/page2.html
I dont want my users to see the html file in url
Instead I want to show only localhost:3000/page2
How can i achieve this? Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Check the anchor tags in your HTML files. If you have for example <a href="/page2.html">Go to page 2</a>, it will append ".html" to the URL. It should be <a href="/page2">Go to page 2</a>.

Comment: It is /page2 only and not page2.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .ejs files for MVC nodejs.

https://github.com/Elnur21/smart-edu/tree/main/smart-edu